# AZ-900, To What should an application connect to retrieve security tokens?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-keyvault

I was practicing for the AZ-900, and I am not able to find the relevant solution for this question.

Only one option is correct.

#### To What should an application connect to retrieve security tokens ?

- An Azure Account
- Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
- A Certificate store
- An Azure Key Vault

In my opinion answer should be azure key vault since it can be used to store certificates, passwords, and tokens.

Comment: Aside from this being off-topic (you're asking opinions on exam questions): Please don't place solutions/answers in questions - that's not where they belong. As such, I've rolled back your edit. If you want to post your answer, please post only as a proper answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon
Hi David,
Thank you providing input that we should not post the answer with the questions.

I am wondering how is it off-topic , since i am not able to get the proper explanation on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A security token is a specific concept related to OAuth 2.0 and OIDC, so the answer is Azure AD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens

Answer (score 1):

I believe answer should be Azure Key Vault. The Azure Key Vault stores the certificates, tokens, and connection strings. Azure Key Vault helps you provide tokens to your application. By contrast, Azure AD is the identity provider, and helps to authenticate the user, but it's not provided to applications

Answer (score 1):

An application connect to retrieve security tokens - so the connect to happen with Azure AD. Once it connected/authenticated then it can retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same question right now and I also answered "the key vault".
However, reading again the question, it specifically asks for "security tokens", and not for "secrets".

That's why I believe that is the AD.
The link from Jason P. is the "quid".

Answer (score 0):

```
-> Azure Key Vault is used to store secrets for server applications
-> You need to connect to Azure Active Directory to retrieve these security tokens
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is (to what ) so answer is Azure AD , IF The question is ( from what ) the answer should be Azure Key Vault . I think so ..